# Convert the value in an Option to another type

Tags: scala, scala-option

I'm trying to do something that seems like it should have a straight forward syntax/function in scala.  I just don't know what that is.  I'm trying to convert the contained value of an Option (if it is not None) to another type.

Simply I want to know what the code would be if I wanted to implement the following function

```
def myFunc(inVal:Option[Double]):Option[BigDecimal] = {
    //Code I need goes here
}
```

Note: I am not actually implementing this function, it just is the clearest way for me to demonstrate what I need

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
def myFunc(inVal: Option[Double]): Option[BigDecimal] =
  inVal map {d => d: BigDecimal}
```

In general if you want to transform value in container (`Option`, `Seq`, `List`, `Try`, `Future`, etc) you should use method `map` on this container.

Method `map` accepts lambda (function) as parameter and applies this function to all elements. `map` should not change the count of elements: `map` on `Some` will never return `None`.

You could use method `BigDecimal.apply` to convert `Double` to `BigDecimal` like this:

```
BigDecimal(1.1)
// res0: scala.math.BigDecimal = 1.1
```

But there is also an implicit conversion from `Double` to `BigDecimal`, so you could just specify desired type like this:

```
1.1: BigDecimal
// res0: scala.math.BigDecimal = 1.1

val bd: BigDecimal = 1.2
```

PS: type inference allows you to use `d => d` instead of `d => d: BigDecimal` here, but it will make your code very unclear.

Comment: @som-snytt: Updated, though I can't imagine someone would try to use `map` this way.

Comment: @senia Really helpful answer.  I wasn't conceptualizing the Option just as another container and what I really wanted to do was transform the contents of the container. Really helpful to think that way and hopefully will stop me from getting stuck in other places in the future.

Comment: @RandallSchulz: I guess "container" is better for beginners, than "M-word", though `Reader` is not a container.

Comment: @RandallSchulz all this one needs is the F-word :)

Comment: @senia reader could easily be seen as a container. Take an infinite stream, which I think most people would agree is "containerish". That's isomorphic to a reader from natural numbers, with the same flavor of monad/applicative/functor.

Comment: @MyseriousDan: could you please describe isomorphism between `Stream` and `scalaz.Reader`?

Comment: Keep in mind I said infinite stream (in the sense we'd use it in Haskell) and not potentially infinite stream, as Scala's is. An infinite one is trivially equivalent to a function from naturals to the element type, where that function is just the indexing function. That function is also a reader. You can also treat finite lists this way if you think of "numbers less than K" as a distinct type (called `Fin` in many languages). Potentially infinite lists like Haskell's list or Scala's stream are trickier: You can have `Either[InfiniteStream,List]` but that's subtly different from `Stream`.

Comment: The difference is that they contain all the same elements, in theory, but you can't decide whether `Stream` is finite in finite time, and you can with the `Either` version.

Comment: @senia forgot to highlight you so you'd see the responses :)

Comment: @MyseriousDan: thank you, I got the idea. From this point any pure function is just a map.

Answer (score 2):

```
def myFunc(inVal: Option[Double]): Option[BigDecimal] = inVal map { BigDecimal(_) }
```

or

```
def myFunc(inVal: Option[Double]): Option[BigDecimal] = inVal map { BigDecimal.apply }
```

It works because Option is a `Functor` (no monadic trick in this simple use case)

Answer (score 0):

Extending **@senia**'s and **@Yann Moisan**'s answers, if you want to keep something wrapped inside `Option[]` while still supplying a **default value** during conversion phase (could be a requirement down-the-line in your *framework*), you can use this:

```
def myFunc(inVal: Option[Double]): Option[BigDecimal] = {
  Some(inVal.map(BigDecimal(_)).getOrElse(BigDecimal(0.0)))
}
```

It would not only convert your `Option[Double]` into `Option[BigDecimal]` but also create a *default* `BigDecimal` (with value `0.0`) in case the origin `Option[Double]` turns out to be null.